# Combine 2 or more tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

products table

```
products
productid | sellerid | productprice
```

sameproduct table

```
sameproduct
productid | sellerid | productprice
```

sellers table

```
sellers
sellerid | sellername | selleraddress
```

The sellerid is foreign key to both the tables products and sameproduct.
I want to show the seller details for a particular productid which may be present in both tables products and sameproduct.

Comment: First thing, if both table have same structure then you should combine.If you want to organize products of different type or categories then you can add a field like category or type and based on that you can filter.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan Not necessarily true. 1:1 relationships is a common approach in the Relational Model to remove null values. Also, it may be used to improve performance on tables used on different applications or by different roles. If most people only use 4 columns but there's one person who needs to use 40 columns, then splitting the table will improve the app performance for most people. Also a typical approach for database segmentation.

Answer (score 3):

This Might Help You.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sellers 
     INNER JOIN sameproduct ON sellers.sellerid = sameproduct.sellerid  
     INNER JOIN products ON sellers.sellerid = products.sellerid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
select sellers.* from products
inner join sellers on products.sellerid =sellers.sellerid
where productid=@productid
UNION
select sellers.* from sameproduct
inner join sellers on sameproduct.sellerid =sellers.sellerid
where productid=@productid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can UNION both tables, and after that do something:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT * FROM products 
        UNION ALL SELECT * FROM sameproduct
       ) AS p
  JOIN sellers AS s ON (s.sellerid = p.sellerid)
 WHERE productid = @productid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `JOIN` `products` and `sellers` tables to get the desired output, e.g.:

```
SELECT s.sellerid, s.sellername, s.selleraddress
FROM sellers JOIN products p ON s.sellerid = p.sellerid
WHERE p.productid = ?
```

Please note that it will return multiple rows if a product has more than one seller.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL to join three tables called `products`, `sameproduct` and `sellers`:

```
select s.*
from products p 
inner join sameproduct ps on p.sellerid = ps.sellerid
inner join sellers s on ps.sellerid = s.sellerid 
where productid =in_product_id
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you need? You left join the sellers table to both tables and select only the records where the productid is found in one of the two product tables.

```
declare @productid int
set @productid = 1

select s.*, p.productid, sp.productid
  from sellers s
    left join product p
      on s.sellerid = p.sellerid
    left join sameproduct sp
      on s.sellerid = sp.sellerid
  where p.productid = @productid 
      or sp.productid = @productid
```

Comment: The solution with the UNION from AlbertoCh and Roman Tkachuk should work as well!

Answer (score 0):

You want to show the *seller* for a product, so you'd select from the sellers table (no join). You get the seller IDs for the product in an `IN` clause (or an `EXISTS` clause if you prefer this).

```
select *
from sellers
where sellerid in (select sellerid from products where productid = 12345)
   or sellerid in (select sellerid from sameproduct where productid = 12345);
```

or

```
select *
from sellers
where sellerid in (select sellerid from products where productid = 12345
                   union all 
                   select sellerid from sameproduct where productid = 12345);
```

It may be preferrable to make products and sameproduct one table, though.